# How to send .gif files recorded in our device thro some chatting Apps to be specific ( WhatsApp, Hiken)

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, camera, instagram

I found an camera App named **Cameringo** from Playstore and it has an option to record an small time period of actions and save it in .gif format so i tried and recorded some .gif animations and it was animated while i see those on my gallery and when i share it via whatsapp or hike or instagram the file is sent as a normal picture and no animations were seen in my Friends device i tried it with many devices same result is found is there any way to send those .gif animation via Whatsapp and instagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Simple option of renaming `.gif` to `.mp3`. Person receiving it needs to download and do the opposite (this trick can be used for any other kind of file also)

   2. Converting it to video by using on line converters mentioned here [How to send animated gifs through whatsapp?](http://www.askmefast.com/How_to_send_animated_gifs_through_whatsapp-qna5763419.html#q4771577)
   3. Using [File Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.fileshare) Which sends any type of file as link, recipient needs to download and doesn't need to install this app on his device.
   4. Using modded whatsapp (you will need to Google as I don't trust these )
   5. For Hiken app, you could send `.gif` link after uploading, using [imgur](http://m.imgur.com/)

**Note** using modded WhatsApp is a possible security risk . I am unable to recall where I had read it but will link it when I locate

Answer (score 2):

Use the app GroupMe with it you can send gifs and the other person will receive it with no problems. 
[Android GroupMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groupme.android)